# Is it possible to not display a SpriteSheetBundle in bevy?

Tags: rust, bevy

I want to set the `display` of a `SpriteSheetBundle` entity to "None," but the `SpriteSheetBundle` does not have a `style` property:

```
/// A Bundle of components for drawing a single sprite from a sprite sheet (also referred
/// to as a `TextureAtlas`)
#[derive(Bundle, Clone, Default)]
pub struct SpriteSheetBundle {
    /// The specific sprite from the texture atlas to be drawn, defaulting to the sprite at index 0.
    pub sprite: TextureAtlasSprite,
    /// A handle to the texture atlas that holds the sprite images
    pub texture_atlas: Handle<TextureAtlas>,
    /// Data pertaining to how the sprite is drawn on the screen
    pub transform: Transform,
    pub global_transform: GlobalTransform,
    /// User indication of whether an entity is visible
    pub visibility: Visibility,
    /// Algorithmically-computed indication of whether an entity is visible and should be extracted for rendering
    pub computed_visibility: ComputedVisibility,
}
```

The `visibility` property is not sufficient for me because the collider still exists.

How can I achieve not displaying the entity?

Comment: Can you clarify? `style` and `display` are used in UI components in which case you would use [`AtlasImageBundle`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/ui/node_bundles/struct.AtlasImageBundle.html) instead.

Comment: I spawn a SpriteSheetBundle with a sprite selected by the index on my TextureAtlasSprite. To fix my problem what I did is to put the `visibility` at `Hidden` and `remove` the `collider`

Comment: There is no collider in a `SpriteSheetBundle`. If you do have a collider, then it won't be affected by `Visibility` since it only affects rendering and not physics.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's why I removed it